# cacti on ubuntu 12.04 does not show images, rrdtool says nothing

Tags: graph, ubuntu-12.04, rrdtool, cacti

I've tried to instal cacti via apt-get and from sources, and i get the same result - when viewing the graph - there is no images...

done few things :

chowning of rra and log folders,
fixed crontab issue (crontab -u {apache user} instead of default seting user inside of crontab),
configured snmp (auth,v3,publicdomain).

when I launch poller.php from console  - it's ok, from crontab - ok too, timestamps on ls -l rra folder are updated,
if i launch from console the graph statement from debug information ("rrdtool create" statement) i get the png image, some times with nan, but i get the image in my home folder ( rrdtool create > test.png).
but from browser - i get nothing...

(cacti) logs does not contain any errors...

i don't know what to do next...
ps. rebuilding rra cache doesn't solve the problem.

---

installed soft:

```
apache2 
nginx
mysql
php5
rrdtool
snmp
net-snmp (from sources)
spine
php-snmp
php-gd
and more.. if need some specific information - I will provide it
```